# Submit a form and display it in a javascript div instead of iframe?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, iframe

I was told to use Javascript Div instead of iframe, Im totally new to this so please be slow, lol

Basically I want to post form results that im getting from a external site to display it on my current or another page.

Hide it when not submitted

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Read up on [`SOP`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: Please add the code you've tried. Have you ever made an AJAX request before?

Answer (score 0):

Just as @MattDiamant recommends, you should try AJAX. One good introductory reference I can recommend is http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

If you are a bit clearer on nature of the problem, I could have provided a more direct solution, but generally AJAX seem to be a very good way exchanging data with a server, and updating parts of a web page - without reloading the whole page.

Comment: i'm totally new to this. So im not sure whats the best. I have a form that im submitting to a external booking engine and I want either to have a iframe or div or direct to another page with results.

Comment: You can only do that if the "external booking engine" allow you to use the data send from their server in such away. If they are allow you to do that, just go with AJAX for passing and retrieving the data, it is your best option in this case. As I said before, read that link I posted earlier, it is very good place to start with easy.

Comment: ok this company uses same booking engine, what are they using?http://www.montrosetravel.com/cars

Comment: As I said, I don't think any site will allow you to use their resources like that, unless they have some kind of API for such. You might even be violating copyright law if you manage to get it working like you describe it. I will edit my previous post to describe a possible solution on how to go about it, without breaking any law

Answer (score 0):

=====Possible Solution==============

After going through the external page you are planning to use. Here is what I will suggest you do.

1. You will need to study the URL of the site search result. 
   Take for example, I will search for the follo:
   Drop off: Same Location
   Pick up location: New York, NY (JFK-John F Kennedy Intl)
   Pick up date: 03/22/2013     Time: 3:00pm
   Drop off date: 03/30/2013     Time: 7:00pm
   Do you have car rental company preference? No preference

Here is the link to the result page:

https://booking.montrosetravel.com/travel/car/availability.rvlx?country_code=US&pickup_city=JFK&return_city=JFK&pickup_month=03&pickup_day=22&pickup_time=15&return_month=03&return_day=30&return_time=19&pickup_time_minutes=0&return_time_minutes=0&car_type=ACAR&car_company=&nonairport_location=A&car_sort=&country_code=&pickup_year=2013&return_year=2013&car_renter_age=0&transmission=automatic&air_conditioning=ac&SESSID=23eb40d2087e58696a40c68dfaa1b0f2

Breaking this URL down into pieces, it will give you an idea on how the website works, all you need to do is to figure out the parameters that were passed into their search engine.

If you are able to do the above, you can supply any parameters through your site and you will get the desired result by doing the second step below.

1. After pass the correct parameters you can use iframe to display the whole page on you site, like this:

   ```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

         <body>

               <iframe src="https://booking.montrosetravel.com/travel/car/availability.rvlx?country_code=US&pickup_city=JFK&return_city=JFK&pickup_month=03&pickup_day=22&pickup_time=15&return_month=03&return_day=30&return_time=19&pickup_time_minutes=0&return_time_minutes=0&car_type=ACAR&car_company=&nonairport_location=A&car_sort=&country_code=&pickup_year=2013&return_year=2013&car_renter_age=0&transmission=automatic&air_conditioning=ac&SESSID=23eb40d2087e58696a40c68dfaa1b0f2">
                    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
               </iframe>

         </body>
   </html>
   ```

I hope this help

FM

Comment: by using this, you don't need AJAX